# Math behind Maximum-Product in Rod-Cutting Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, contest-math, products, programming

I am self-learning Data Structures and Algorithms and I came across a problem recently.

> Given a rod of length `n`, find the optimal way to cut the rod into smaller rods in order to maximize product of profit of each of the smaller rod. Assume each rod of length `i` has profit `i`.

For example, consider a rod of length $4$. The maximum product will be $4$ ( $=2\times2$ or not cutting it ).

For another example, a rod of length $6$ has maximum product $9$ ( $=3\times3$ ).

---

I have designed my program and successfully solved this problem. When I looked into the problem more, I found a pattern:

> The maximum product can be obtained be repeatedly cutting parts of length $3$ while length is greater than $4$, keeping the last part as length of $2$, $3$ or $4$.

For example,

1. Length $14$: maximum product $= 3\times3\times3\times3\times\color{blue}{2}=162$.
2. Length $15$: maximum product $= 3\times3\times3\times3\times\color{blue}{3}=243$.
3. Length $16$: maximum product $= 3\times3\times3\times3\times\color{blue}{4}=324$.

This fact is interesting, but I'm not able to prove it mathematically. Any suggestions, hints or answers will be appreciated. Thanks for reading this post.

Source: https://www.techiedelight.com/maximum-product-rod-cutting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is essentially [IMO $1976/P4$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1976_IMO_Problems/Problem_4).

The idea is that using maximum number of $3$'s is most efficient.
Since larger numbers can be broken down into smaller ones, keeping the sum same but increasing the product.

For example, if any part is $5$ it can be broken down into a $3$ and $2$ increasing the product contribution from $5$ to $6$. A $6$ into two $3$'s - product contribution : $6$ to $9$. A $7$ into $3,4$ or $3,2,2$ - product contribution : $7$ to $12$.

The reason is simple inequality :
$$xy \ge (x+y)\cdot 1 \iff (x-1)(y-1)\ge 1$$

That is, it is beneficial to convert a single part $(x+y)$ into two parts $x$ and $y$ as long as $x,y \ge 2$. Now for size $6=2+2+2=3+3$. But $$3\times 3 > 2 \times 2 \times 2$$

So we observe use of maximum $3$'s is optimal.

For $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, all parts should be $3$'s. For $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$,  $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ all $3$'s except for one $4$ and one $2$ can be used respectively.